# Presto with C# for MongoDB or Azure Blob as data store

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, blob, presto

I am looking for ways I can access data in MongoDB OR Azure Blob through Presto from C#.

1. Any drivers
2. Any API
3. Any direct http calls to Presto
4. Prepared solutions in Azure/AWS

Comment: _"Presto is an open source distributed **SQL query engine** for running interactive analytic ..."_ will that go well along with MongoDB ?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, there is MongoDB connector in Presto https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/mongodb.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try the ODBC driver: https://trino.io/resources.html#odbc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we have moved away from Presto for now. Will give it a try if needed in future.

Comment: @Kamil Bajda-Pawlikowski this works for only JAVA , not in C#, how to make it work in C#

Answer (score 0):

100% C# client for Presto/Trino: https://github.com/bamcis-io/PrestoClient

ADO.NET Provider implementation based on PrestoClient: https://github.com/nreco/presto-ado